# Member Routes with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I had these routes when I used my own custom authentication system:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

Now with devise I need to switch to:

```
devise_for :users
```

How do I incorporate those member routes with Devise?

Comment: I guess I need clarification: what routes do you want to have when the dust settles? some from devise and some from your users? or all from devise?

Comment: i want the /following and /followers member routes. It can be from users but then I don't want all of the other user routes that devise handles (new, edit etc.). On the flip side, I'd be fine with making them from devise and getting rid of users all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use match or get and just specify those routes alone if you want.

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :users
match '/users/:id/following', :to => 'users#following'   #or your route
match '/users/:id/followers', :to => 'users#followers'   #or your route
```

Alternatively, you can specify resourceful routes for certain actions, but it seems as though you want to use devise for everything. As far as I know, devise doesn't auto-create an index to view all the registered users, so I usually end up doing something like this:

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :users
resources  :users, :only => [:index, :show] do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

Is this what you had in mind? Routes most user actions to devise, but keeps index, show, following, etc. in your own Users controller.

Comment: I have done the exact same problem. I have done as suggested in the 2. example of routes.rb, however `rake routes`interprets it as collection actions for some reason, even though it's wrapped in a `member do` block?